# How to archiveArtifact a specific directory?

Tags: c#, jenkins

I am not able to understand how to use archiveArtifact for a specific directory. I have a workspace inside which, there is a `DemoWebApp` directory and inside that, there is an `artifacts` directory which has my `dotnet publish` command's output(only files, not directories). Now, I just want to archive that folder. But when I do:

`archiveArtifacts artifacts: 'DemoWebApp/artifacts/*.*'`

it says

`‘DemoWebApp/artifacts/*.*’ doesn’t match anything, but ‘*.*’ does. Perhaps that’s what you mean?`

So, I tried doing:

`archiveArtifacts artifacts: '*.*'` and `archiveArtifacts artifacts: '**/*.*'`

and both yield my entire project's folder as a zip file. And the project's folder also has this `DemoWebApp/artifacts/*.*` path. I also tried adding `./` at the beginning so that there is no path issues but still the same error. So, why is it not allowing me to just archive that specific folder? What am I missing?

edit: here's a directory structure of jenkins workspace on my machine
[image]

So, when I do `archiveArtifact '**'`, all files inside `MyApp` get zipped without having any `containing directory`. So, I tried, `archiveArtifact 'DemoWebApp/artifacts/*.*'` or `archiveArtifact './DemoWebApp/artifacts/*.*'`
or `archiveArtifact '**/DemoWebApp/artifacts/*.*'`, but got no success.

Comment: `‘./DemoWebApp/artifacts’ doesn’t match anything, but ‘DemoWebApp/artifacts’ does. Perhaps that’s what you mean?` Right. but why does adding `/*.*' to the end doesn't work?

Comment: `DemoWebApp/artifacts` gives error. I am trying `DemoWebApp/artifacts/**`

Comment: `DemoWebApp/artifacts/**` works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use:

```
DemoWebApp/artifacts/**
```